# How to execute external JS file blocked by users' adblockers

Tags: javascript, adblock

We use an external service (Monetate) to serve JS to our site such that we can perform adhoc presentation-layer site updates without going through the process of a site re-deploy - which in our case is a time-consuming, monolithic process which we can only afford to do about once per month.

However, users who use adblockers in the browser do not see some of these presentation-layer updates. This can negatively affect their experience of the site as we sometimes include time-sensitive promotions that those users may not be aware of.

To work around this, I was thinking to duplicate the JavaScript file that Monetate is serving and host it on a separate infrastructure from the site. That way, it we needed to make updates to it, we could do so as needed without doing a full site re-deploy.

However, I'm wondering if there is some way to work around the blocking of the Monetate JS file and somehow execute the remote Monetate JS file from our own JS code in such a way that adblockers would not be able to block it? This avoid the need to duplicate the file.

Answer (score 1):

If that file is blocked by adblockers, chances are that it is used to serve ads. In fact, your description of *time-sensitive promotions* sounds an awful lot like ads, just not for an external provider, *but for your own site*.

Since adblockers usually match the URL, the easiest solution would indeed be to rehost this file, if possible under a different name. Instead of hosting a static copy, you can also implement a simple proxy with the equivalent of `<?php readfile('http://monetdate.com/file.js');` or apache's [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html). While this will increase load times and can fail if the remote host goes down, it means the client will always get the newest version of the file.

Apart from using a different URL, there is no client-side solution - adblockers are included in the browser (or an extension thereof), and you cannot modify that code for good reasons.

Beware that adblockers may decide to block your URL too, if the script is indeed used to serve ads.

Answer (score 0):

Monetate if probably blacklisted in Adblock, so you can't do nothing about.

I think that self-hosting Monetate script would require to keep it updated by checking for new versions from time to time (maintaining it could become a pain in the ass).

A good solution in my opinion is to inform your users about that limitation with a clear message.

Or, you can get in touch with Monetate and ask for a solution.